# Unable to import package in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

**Issue** : Unable to import modules in Pycharm3.5

For example : Picking ***paramiko*** package

Package is already installed

```
C:\Users\rj>pip3 install paramiko
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (3.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.5 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko) (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\rj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko) (2.19)
```

Python script :

```
from paramiko import *

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.10.220.28", username="root", password="mavenir", port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls")
ssh_output = stdout.read()
print(ssh_output)
```

Observed below error

```
C:\Users\rj\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rj/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ssh.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rj/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ssh.py", line 1, in <module>
    from paramiko import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Environment variables also added.

Observing this issue in most of the packages

Comment: Which python interpreter do you have configured in the settings?

Comment: Python 3.7    interpreter

Comment: You're showing that you've installed `paramiko` on your system instead of your venv. Are you sure it is installed in your venv as well? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pycharm, go to `File-->Settings--Project-->Project Interpreter`. Then hit the plus sign, and type `paramiko`.

Installing your packages from within Pycharm helps ensure that you're always installing it in your venv.

If this isn't the solution, it should move your investigation forward and will answer `@Cani`'s question.